# c , add numbers result strange

Tags: c

I was solving the problem of adding numbers
ex) 123456789 -> 45,  700000000000 -> 7

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, a, sum = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);   //digit
    scanf("%d", &a);   //number
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a == 10)
        {
            sum += 1;
        }
        else if (a != 10)
        {
            sum += a % 10;
            a = a / 10;
        }
    }
    printf("%ld", sum);
}
```

I put
11
10987654321
and result
-56
So I fix it

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int n, a, sum = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%d", &a);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a == 10)
        {
            sum += 1;
        }
        else if (a != 10)
        {
            sum += a % 10;
            a = a / 10;
        }
    }
    printf("%ld", sum);
}
```

Using unsigned int
but the result is 56 not 46
I don't know what is problem
(I'm korean my english is not so good. sry)

Comment: What is the purpose of `a` and `n`? How long is `unsigned int` on your system? If it is 32 bits, you cannot enter `10987654321`.

Comment: What case is `if ( a==10)` supposed to handle?

Comment: a is number and b is number of given numbers,

Comment: Do you mean number of digits in the given number?

Comment: ah If the number of numbers exceeds 10, an error occurs so I add (a==10) but it doesn't work if i can't use unsigned int, than can i use unsigned long long?

Comment: yes! number of digits

Comment: `scanf("%u", ...)` for objects of `unsigned` type.

Comment: 1) What error? 2) Have you checked what the size of integers is on your system? 3) Why do you ask for number of digits? You can determine that without asking user.

Comment: The only loop you need is `while (a!=0)` and you don't need any of your `if`. Besides that you should enable warnings in your compiler. For GCC you can use `-Wall -Wextra`. It should tell you that your `printf` command is wrong as you pass wrong type.

Comment: when `if (a == 10)` is false, there is no need to test `if (a != 10)` in the else part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The largest number that can be represented by an `unsigned int` is 4294967295. You need to either use `long long` or `unsigned long long`

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long long int n, a, sum = 0;
    scanf("%lld", &n);   //digit
    scanf("%lld", &a);   //number
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a == 10)
        {
            sum += 1;
        }
        else if (a != 10)
        {
            sum += a % 10;
            a = a / 10;
        }
    }
    printf("%lld", sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing: 10.987.654.321 is greater than `2^32` (which is 4.294.967.296). If, on your system, `unsigned int` is 4 bytes long, then it's 32 bits, and the maximum value it can represent is `2^32`.

A little program to check the size of `unsigned int`:

```
/* uint.c
 */
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("unsigned int: %zu\n", sizeof(unsigned int));    
    return 0;
}
```

On my system, `unsigned int` is 4 bytes. Therefore, we need something bigger than 4 bytes to hold the number you want to input. So use `unsigned long long int`.

Furthermore, you should use the correct format conversion in [`scanf(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html). And the resulting program is:

```
/* llu.c
 */
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned long long int num;
    printf("unsigned long long int: %zu\n", sizeof(unsigned long long int));

    scanf("%llu", &num);
    printf("num: %llu\n", num);

    return 0;
}
```

You can enter the big number in this program and it will print it correctly (in case your computer really uses 8 bytes for `unsigned long long int`).

You resulting program is:

```
/* so.c
 */
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long long int n, a, sum = 0;
    scanf("%llu", &n);
    scanf("%llu", &a);

    printf("n: %llu\n", n);
    printf("a: %llu\n", a);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (a == 10) {
            sum += 1;
        } else if (a != 10) {
            sum += a % 10;
            a = a / 10;
        }
    }

    printf("Result: %llu\n", sum);
}
```

And the output:

```
$ ./so
11 10987654321 
n: 11
a: 10987654321
Result: 47
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply print and check max and minimum values of types on your system:
himits.h contains some handy definitions

```
SCHAR_MIN      : minimum value for a signed char
SCHAR_MAX      : maximum value for a signed char
UCHAR_MAX      : maximum value for an unsigned char
CHAR_MIN       : minimum value for a char
CHAR_MAX       : maximum value for a char
SHRT_MIN       : minimum value for a short
SHRT_MAX       : maximum value for a short
USHRT_MAX      : maximum value for an unsigned short
INT_MIN        : minimum value for an int
INT_MAX        : maximum value for an int
UINT_MAX       : maximum value for an unsigned int
LONG_MIN       : minimum value for a long
LONG_MAX       : maximum value for a long
ULONG_MAX      : maximum value for an unsigned long
LLONG_MIN      : minimum value for a long long
LLONG_MAX      : maximum value for a long long
ULLONG_MAX     : maximum value for an unsigned long long
PTRDIFF_MIN    : minimum value of ptrdiff_t
PTRDIFF_MAX    : maximum value of ptrdiff_t
SIZE_MAX       : maximum value of size_t
SIG_ATOMIC_MIN : minimum value of sig_atomic_t
SIG_ATOMIC_MAX : maximum value of sig_atomic_t
WINT_MIN       : minimum value of wint_t
WINT_MAX       : maximum value of wint_t
WCHAR_MIN      : minimum value of wchar_t
WCHAR_MAX      : maximum value of wchar_t
CHAR_BIT       : number of bits in a char
MB_LEN_MAX     : maximum length of a multibyte character in bytes
```

For example you can print:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
    printf("int min: %d int max %d\n", INT_MIN, INT_MAX);
    printf("long int min: %ld long int max %ldu\n", LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX);
    printf("long long int min: %lld long long int max %ldu\n", LLONG_MIN, LLONG_MAX);
}
```

on gotbolt system:

```
int min: -2147483648 int max 2147483647
long int min: -9223372036854775808 long int max 9223372036854775807
long long int min: -9223372036854775808 long long int max 9223372036854775807
```

When you print it for your system you will see if your result or assignment does not **overflow** the maximum or minimum value. Integer overflow and uderflow is an Undefined Behaviour (UB) in C.

Answer (score -3):

recheck

#include<stdio.h>

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int n, a, sum = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%d", &a);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a == 10)
        {
            sum += 1;
        }
        else if (a != 10)
        {
            sum += a % 10;
            a = a / 10;
        }
    }
    printf("%ld", sum);
}
```

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer.